# Error in integral in Gradshteyn Ryzhik

Tags: integration

In formula 4.224 12 in the 8. edition of the Table of Integrals, Series, and Products is an error: In the case $a^2=1$ both equations should hold, but they are not equal. I think the second equation (i.e. $\int_0^\pi \ln(1+a\cos x)dx = 2 \pi \ln \frac{|a|}{2}$ ($a^2 \geq 1$) is wrong and it should be $$\int_0^\pi \ln((1+a\cos x)^2)dx = 2 \pi \ln \frac{|a|}{2}$$ This would also solve the problem, that the argument of the logarithm gets negative if $a^2 \geq 1$. Can someone confirm this and/or does someone know how to prove this?

Answer (score 5):

this is entry 172 in the 2005 [Errata](http://www.mathtable.com/errata/gr6_errata.pdf), which somehow didn't make it properly into the 8th edition.